# async не работает с локальными файлами

Tags: javascript

Почему async не работает с файлами с компьютера, но работает, если подключить скрипт через какой-либо сайт?

Например этот способ работает:

```
<script async src="https://...somepath/script.js"></script>
```

А этот способ ждет, пока я нажму ОК и потом уже подгружает всю страницу:

```
<script async src="D:\somepath/script.js"></script>
```

script.js содержит:

```
alert("Hello world!");
```

Comment: а в чем по твоему заключается работа `async`?

Comment: Мне кажется что при загрузке скрипта с локального диска технология попросту не применима и браузер не берет в учет `async`!

Comment: "А этот способ ждет, пока я нажму ОК и потом уже подгружает всю страницу" Может быть не "подгружает", а "отображает"?

Comment: @Дмытрык Да, отображает

Comment: а теперь возвращаемся к вопросу @Grundy

Comment: @Дмытрык, ну, в моем понимании async позволяет браузеру отображать страницу, не дожидаясь, пока выполнится скрипт

Comment: async позволяет браузеру подгружать страницу, не дожидаясь, пока выполнится скрипт

Comment: @Дмытрык хм, таки, мне все равно непонятно, почему один и тот же скрипт с async работает по разному в зависимости от того, где находится файл скрипта?